# Android 14 build completed successfully , but emulator not working

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-source, android-14

```
lunch aosp_x86_64 

m -j16
```

TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_x86_64 build completed successfully.

```
$ emulator

INFO|Android emulator version 31.3.9.0 (build_id 9070145) (CL:N/A)
INFO|Storing crashdata in: /tmp/android-android/emu-crash.db, detection is enabled
INFO|Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
WARNING|encryption is off
INFO|Info: Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway. ((null):0, (null))
INFO|added library /home/android/aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so
qemu-system-x86_64: Could not open '/home/android/aosp/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/userdata-qemu.img': No such file or directory
```

build hasnt generated the userdata-qemu.img which is causing the emulator to fail.

Comment: The solution is simple but you should also add details like your host PC software details, the branch you are using etc. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, I think the target `aosp_x86_64` builds for the GSI?

For doing an emulator build I would suggest you to use the lunch target `sdk_phone_x86_64` and then launch the emulator accordingly.

Ref: [Using Android Emulator virtual devices](https://source.android.com/docs/setup/create/avd)

Comment: in the lunch for A14 there is not  sdk_phone_x86_64 only sdk_pc_x86_64-userdebug

Comment: You can manually do it, instead of selecting from the lunch menu. If you manually type `lunch sdk_phone_x86_64-userdebug` it should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

You must check your real device sdk. Its different from emulator sdk u can take error message.Take care of yourself.